# Node: 'sequential/dense/MatMul' In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [4] vs. [4,24]' error of keras.model.predict() using cartpole exgample

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I try to train a cartpole, an example of reinforcement learning, using DQN.

But I got a running error.

At this point

```
target = self.model.predict(states)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, even looking at the documentation that describes what the function does.

link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Is the model declaration invalid?

Does anyone know of a solution?

I need help

version: keras 2.10.0, python 3.10.13, gym 0.26.2

below is all the code

```
import sys
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential

class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.render = False
        self.load_model = False

        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size

        self.discount_factor = 0.99
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.999
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.train_start = 1000

        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)

        self.model = self.build_model()
        self.target_model = self.build_model()

        self.update_target_model()

    def build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def update_target_model(self):
        self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())

    def get_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        else:
            q_value = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(q_value[0])

    def append_sample(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def train_model(self):
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
 
        mini_batch = random.sample(self.memory, self.batch_size)

        states = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.state_size))
        next_states = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.state_size))
        actions, rewards, dones = [], [], []

        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            states[i] = mini_batch[i][0]
            actions.append(mini_batch[i][1])
            rewards.append(mini_batch[i][2])
            next_states[i] = mini_batch[i][3]
            dones.append(mini_batch[i][4])

        #error
        target = self.model.predict(states)
        target_val = self.target_model.predict(next_states)

        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            if dones[i]:
                target[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i]
            else:
                target[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i] + self.discount_factor * (np.amax(target_val[i]))

        self.model.fit(states, target, batch_size=self.batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="human")
    random_seed = 82
    env.action_space.seed(random_seed)
    state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    observation, info = env.reset(seed=random_seed)
    EPISODES = 1000

    agent = DQNAgent(state_size, env.action_space.n)
    scores, episodes = [], []

    for e in range(EPISODES):
        done = False
        score = 0
        state = env.reset()[0]

        while not done:

            action = agent.get_action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)
            reward = reward if not done or score == 499 else -100

            agent.append_sample(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            if len(agent.memory) >= agent.train_start:
                agent.train_model()

            score += reward
            state = next_state

            if done:
                agent.update_target_model()

                score = score if score == 500 else score + 100
                scores.append(score)
                episodes.append(e)
                print("episode:", e, "  score:", score, "  memory length:",
                      len(agent.memory), "  epsilon:", agent.epsilon)

                if np.mean(scores[-min(10, len(scores)):]) > 490:
                    sys.exit()
```

This is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    action = agent.get_action(state)
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 48, in get_action
    q_value = self.model.predict(state)
  File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/dense/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 101, in <module>
      action = agent.get_action(state)
    File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 48, in get_action
      q_value = self.model.predict(state)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2253, in predict
      tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2041, in predict_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2027, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2015, in run_step
      outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1983, in predict_step
      return self(x, training=False)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 557, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 410, in call
      return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 510, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 667, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\cglab\anaconda3\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 241, in call
      outputs = tf.matmul(a=inputs, b=self.kernel)
Node: 'sequential/dense/MatMul'
In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [4] vs. [4,24]
         [[{{node sequential/dense/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_14218]
```

Welcome to all comments. thx.

Comment: What is the shape of `states`? Can you try with `states = np.expand_dims(states, -1)` right before the error?

Comment: Sry, I'm late. shape of  states = (64, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, and it's not where you marked it in the code. The error message even tells one where to look with:

```
Detected at node 'sequential/dense/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 101, in <module>
      action = agent.get_action(state)
    File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3_DQN\main.py", line 48, in get_action
      q_value = self.model.predict(state)  <-------------------------
```

It is in this part:

```
def get_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        else:
            q_value = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(q_value[0])
```

The problem is that `state` is just one state with shape `(4,)`, and a TF model always expects a batch of states. You can fix it with the following line directly above the `predict` call:

```
state = np.expand_dims(state, 0)
```

This will bring it to the shape `(1, 4)`, which is a "batch" of just one example for the model.

Comment: fixed bug. thx :D